# Ubuntu 14.04 turns off after unplugging the charger

Tags: 14.04, power-management, shutdown

I have problem with my Ubuntu 14.04. Every time I unplug the charger, the system is shutting down. It occurs only, when the charger is unplugged from computer, but not when unplugged from the power socket. Surprisingly, when I try it on the second system on my computer (Windows 8.1) everything is fine. Firstly there were also occurring "System program problem detected" pops, but lastly they disappeared.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I don't remember correctly, but after reinstalling the system or moving to the newer version problem disappeared.